# Postgres join vs aggregation on very large partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, partitioning

I have a large table with 100s of millions of rows. Because it is so big, it is partitioned by date range first, and then that partition is also partitioned by a period_id.

```
CREATE TABLE research.ranks
(
    security_id           integer                  NOT NULL,
    period_id             smallint                 NOT NULL,
    classificationtype_id smallint                 NOT NULL,
    dtz                   timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    create_dt             timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    update_dt             timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    rank_1                smallint,
    rank_2                smallint,
    rank_3                smallint
)
CREATE TABLE zpart.ranks_y1990 PARTITION OF research.ranks
    FOR VALUES FROM ('1990-01-01 00:00:00+00') TO ('1991-01-01 00:00:00+00')
    PARTITION BY LIST (period_id);

CREATE TABLE zpart.ranks_y1990p1 PARTITION OF zpart.ranks_y1990
    FOR VALUES IN ('1');
```

every year has a partition and there are another dozen partitions for each year.

I needed to see the result for security_ids side by side for different period_ids.

So the join I initially used was one like this:

```
select          c1.security_id, c1.dtz,c1.rank_2 as rank_2_1, c9.rank_2 as rank_2_9
from            research.ranks c1 
left join      research.ranks c9 on c9.dtz=c9.dtz and c1.security_id=c9.security_id and c9.period_id=9
where           c1.period_id =1 and c1.dtz>now()-interval'10 years'
```

which was slow, but acceptable. I'll call this the JOIN version.

Then, we wanted to show two more period_ids and extended the above to add additional joins on the new period_ids.
This slowed down the join enough for us to look at a different solution.

We found that the following type of query runs about 6 or 7 times faster:

```
            select          c1.security_id, c1.dtz
                            ,sum(case when c1.period_id=1 then c1.rank_2 end) as rank_2_1
                            ,sum(case when c1.period_id=9 then c1.rank_2 end) as rank_2_9
                            ,sum(case when c1.period_id=11 then c1.rank_2 end) as rank_2_11
                            ,sum(case when c1.period_id=14 then c1.rank_2 end) as rank_2_14
            from            research.ranks c1
            where           c1.period_id in (1,11,14,9) and c1.dtz>now()-interval'10 years'
            group by        c1.security_id, c1.dtz;
```

We can use the sum because the table has unique indexes so we know there will only ever be one record that is being "summed". I'll call this the SUM version.

The speed is so much better that I'm questioning half of the code I have written previously! Two questions:

1. Should I be trying to use the SUM version rather than the JOIN version everywhere or is the efficiency likely to be a factor of the specific structure and not likely to be as useful in other circumstances?
2. Is there a problem with the logic of the SUM version in cases that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think your "join" version was ever a good idea anyway. You only have one (partitioned) table so there never was a need for any join.

SUM() is the way to go, but I would use [SUM(...) FILTER(WHERE ..)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) instead of a CASE:

```
SELECT
    security_id,
    dtz,
    SUM(rank_2) FILTER (WHERE period_id = 1) AS rank_2_1,
    SUM(rank_2) FILTER (WHERE period_id = 9) AS rank_2_9,
    SUM(rank_2) FILTER (WHERE period_id = 11) AS rank_2_11,
    SUM(rank_2) FILTER (WHERE period_id = 14) AS rank_2_14,
FROM
    research.ranks
WHERE
    period_id IN ( 1, 11, 14, 9 ) 
AND dtz > now( ) - INTERVAL '10 years' 
GROUP BY
    security_id,
    dtz;
```